# Why do unhandled exceptions cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, exception, segmentation-fault

Here is a minimum example:

```
[joel@maison various] (master *)$ cat throw.cpp 

#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  throw("pouet pouet");
}

[joel@maison various] (master *)$ ./a.out 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Reading the docs, it seems like the default terminate handler is `abort()`. I couldn't find anything about triggering a segfault in the abort man page.

Comment: That is *not* a segfault. That's an abort. What makes you think it's a segfault?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : good catch! I was mislead by the "core dumped" message.

Comment: That is `SIGABRT`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Throwing an exception and not handling it calls `abort()` which raises `SIGABRT`.

You can verify it with the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <signal.h>

extern "C" void handle_sigabrt(int)
{
    std::cout << "Handling and then returning (exiting)" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGABRT, &handle_sigabrt);

  throw("pouet pouet");
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hKgaB6ZxsVa5xsDD)</kbd>

Comment: Nice example. In the live demo, why does it print `terminating with uncaught exception of type char const*` before `Handling and then returning (exiting)`?

Comment: @Muscampester, The first message comes from the implementation when it detects that the exception wasn't caught. It prints the message and then calls `abort`.

Comment: Even forcing stdout flushing with `std::endl`, that message is implementation-specific. The program will terminate as soon as the handler returns. An extremely hacky way (and therefore highly discouraged) to avoid this is not returning (http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pzntUUEAEqHU1eGz). Another method could be using a stack trampoline as featured in boost::coroutine2 (https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/11/coroutines-internals). The use of these techniques requires **extreme caution** to say the least if meant to be deployed in production software.